# Can I use a workflow rule to remove campaign members from one campaign when they are added to another

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have created a process builder that adds members to a SFDC campaign (Campaign A) when they meet certain criteria, as part of the criteria when a member of the campaign is not active for 60 days they get added to another campaign (Campaign B), I would like to remove them from there original campaign (Campaign A) when they get added to campaign b, is there a way to do this that does not involve flows or process builder? I would rather just use a workflow rule for simplicity. thanks

Comment: How would I be able to create a flow in that case that would perform the action I would like?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Workflow Rules nor Process Builder can delete records, such as `CampaignMember`. Only Flow (or Apex) is able to perform deletions.

You can find more about which automation tools have different capabilities under [Which Automation Tool Do I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_which_tool.htm&type=5) in the Salesforce documentation.